# Urban Airship won't allow uploading Production cert

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

When creating a  new Production APNS cert, Apple now creates a combined Sandbox and Production cert:

[image]

When uploading to Urban Airship, Urban Airship gives an error that it’s a Sandbox certificate.

We’ve reached out to Urban Airship, but wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still create separate sandbox and production certificates. In the Apple Developer Center website go to **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**, then to **App IDs**. Edit the app ID for the app you are working on. Scroll down to **Push Notifications** and you will see an area for production certificates as well as sandbox.

[image]

From there you can generate new certificates that are specific to sandbox or production.